# Create 500 rows via phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, gravity-forms-plugin

I need to add 500 different coupons to my SQL table so I don't need to create them manually.

What I need is to add 500 times this row:

```
(62, 1, 1, '{"gravityForm":"1","couponName":"BLUE01","couponCode":"BLUE01","couponAmountType":"flat","couponAmount":0,"startDate":"03\\/01\\/2016","endDate":"03\\/01\\/2018","usageLimit":"1","isStackable":"0","usageCount":""}', 'gravityformscoupons'),
```

where must be different the ID (62, 63, 64, 65...) and the couponName: BLUE01 BLUE02 ... and the same with the couponCode. The rest is the same for each coupon.

How can I do this so I don't destroy my table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a .sql file containing the INSERT statements with a scripting language of your choice and then import it through phpmyadmin **or** insert the rows straight to database from the script

Answer (score 0):

I solved it creating 3 columns in an excel file with the coupon codes, ids, and coupon names and with the formulation CONCAT expand it 500 times and then I edited the SQL file with text-editor and re-upload to my website.

Just in case is useful for someone :).